# How to set the checkbox selected in the first record on the Listgrid?

Tags: smartgwt

my `ListGrid` already set `.setSelectionType(SelectionStyle.SIMPLE)` and  `.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX)`,but now I want to set the checkbox of the first record true when loaded some records.So,how can I code it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
listGrid.addDataArrivedHandler(new DataArrivedHandler() {
    @Override
    void onDataArrived(DataArrivedEvent event) {
        listGrid.selectRecord(0);
    }
});
```